# Ubuntu command isn't recognized by window command prompt - Changing Unix username

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I successfully installed the Window subsystem for Linux a week ago and now wanted to rename the Unix username from old@Desktop:/mnt/c/Users to new@Desktop:/mnt/c/Users

I have digged hard on the internet for a solution and a common solution is:

```
ubuntu config --default-user <new_username>
```

I have tried the command above with the variation of ubuntu1804 as well but it didn't work because the Windows cmd doesn't recognize the the command 'ubuntu'

> 'ubuntu' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I haven't found a solution to this problem anywhere and it seems that nobody has even had this problem. Why is the 'ubuntu' command not recognized by either the bash nor the Window cmd? Is there another way around to change the Unix username?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Search your system for an `Ubuntu` command,  and either run it from where it is or add the directory to your PATH.

Comment: I faced same problem what I did was just typed "ubuntu" and then pressed tab to auto fill it and it gave me "ubuntu2204.exe". So I had to replace "ubuntu" with "ubuntu2204.exe" in my command

Comment: try ubuntu1804 config –default-user root

Comment: if you want root access without password to change defult user password use
"wsl.exe -u root" in windwos command line